# LINQ to EF left join with multiple condition

Tags: linq-to-entities, left-join, multiple-conditions

I am trying to replicate the following SQL using LINQ to EF but with no luck.

```
select * from Role
left join QueueAccess on Role.RoleId = QueueAccess.RoleId and queueId = 361
```

Here's what I've tried.

```
var myAccess = (from role in entity.Role.Include(p => p.QueueAccess)
join qa in entity.QueueAccess
on new { rID = role.RoleId, qID = queueId } equals new { rID = qa.RoleId, qID = qa.QueueId }
select role).ToList();
```

Also tried this.

```
var myAccess = entity.Role.Include(p => p.QueueAccess)
         .Where(x => x.QueueAccess.Any(a => a.QueueId == queueId)).ToList();
```

I keep on getting only the record with the specified queueId but none of the other records where the queueId is null.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

[It's nearly always a mistake to use `join` in LINQ to Entities](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/). Instead, do:

```
var myAccess = (((ObjectQuery)from role in entity.Role
                              where role.QueueAccess.Any(a => a.QueueId == queueId)
                              select role).Include("QueueAccess")).ToList();
```

Comment: I gave this a go and got an exception.
 System.NotSupportedException: Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1'. Only primitive types (such as Int32, String, and Guid) and entity types are supported

This is in relation to (role.QueueAccess == null) that EF is complaining about. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var access = from role in Role
             join oq in (from q in QueueAccess
                         where q.queueId = 361
                         select q) on role.RoleId equals queue.RoleId into oqs
             from queue in oqs.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { role.RoleId, queue.Property };
```

Comment: DefaultIfEmpty() isn't supported in EF from what I've tried. Would you be able to offer a work around? Thanks

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` is supported in EF 4 but not in EF 1.

Comment: @Joe:  Do you have a collection like Role.QueueAccesses in your model?

Comment: Role and QueueAccess are both tables in my EF model if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works too, puts the condition in the ON as oppose to the WHERE clause.

```
join tbl3 in model.phone.Where(p => p.queue == 0  && p.phnkey == key) on x.key equals tbl3.y into a3
                            from phn in a3.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (phn.abc == 0 )
```